# LinkedList iterator remove

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient equivalent for removing elements while iterating the Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection)

```
private LinkedList flights;
```

....

```
public void clear(){

    ListIterator itr = flights.listIterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){


        flights.remove(itr.next());

    }

}
```

....

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
    at section1.FlightQueue.clear(FlightQueue.java:44)
    at section1.FlightTest001.main(FlightTest001.java:22)
```

Whats wrong with it? cant at all understand why the error is given, I am sure i have used the same code on arraylists or arrays and it has worked.

Comment: Why not call `flights.clear()`?

Answer (score 14):

You cannot remove an item from the collection directly while iterating through the elements as this will cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`. `Iterator.remove()` is the accepted safe way to modify a collection during iteration. To avoid seeing an `IllegalStateException`, make sure to call `Iterator.next()`:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
   itr.next();
   itr.remove();
}
```

or as you simply wish to remove all elements in the `Collection`, you could use:

```
flights.clear();
```

See: [Efficient equivalent for removing elements while iterating the Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection)

Comment: itr.remove() produces the an error (btw I need to remove them individually using an interator).

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.remove(Unknown Source)
 at section1.FlightQueue.clear(FlightQueue.java:44)
 at section1.FlightTest001.main(FlightTest001.java:22)

Comment: You need to call `itr.next()`, See update.

Comment: What's the running time of `itr.remove()`?

Comment: ListIterator.remove() runs in O(1). It is not explicitly mentioned in the [Javadoc] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) but the [source code] (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java) suggests so. Scroll to line 918 to see the implementation