# Linkedlist error when removing using an iterator

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LinkedList iterator remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344447/linkedlist-iterator-remove)

```
private LinkedList flights;

...

public FlightQueue() {
    super();
    flights = new LinkedList();
}

...

public void clear(){

   ListIterator itr = flights.listIterator();

   while(itr.hasNext()){
        itr.remove();
   }
}
```

....

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.remove(Unknown Source)
    at section1.FlightQueue.clear(FlightQueue.java:44)
    at section1.FlightTest001.main(FlightTest001.java:22)
```

No idea whats wrong, its showing the error at the first itr.remove().

Comment: same as [1 hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344447/linkedlist-iterator-remove)

Answer (score 6):

> From the [iterator API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):
>   IllegalStateException - if the next method
>   has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called
>   after the last call to the next method

you have to call **iterator.next()** before calling **iterator.remove()**.

```
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        itr.next(); //This would resolve the exception.
        itr.remove();
    }
```

Comment: oh well thank you lol, works now.

Comment: you posted the same question an hour ago, you got the same response. Why posting it again???

Comment: The other question lead to this problem, I thought i would get a faster answer if I posted it as a new question.

Comment: @user1817988 and also, you have to accept an answer which you think has resolved your issue, i see you are new to SO. read here about how would accepting an answer help you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can call **itr.remove()** only if you called **next()** or **previous()** before, because it removes an element that was returned by those methods.

```
public void clear(){
    flights.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use clear() method of LinkedList

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Javadoc for `ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove%28%29). It specifically states:

```
IllegalStateException - neither next nor previous have been called, 
or remove or add have been called after the last call to next or previous.
```

You'll need a `.next()` before the `.remove()` in your posted code fragment.

Cheers,